# JsFiddle code not working

Tags: jsfiddle

I have a better question following up but this is too basic. Is there some problem with my code(syntax) or Is it Jsfiddle which is not working well!

Link :http://jsfiddle.net/HEM7Q/

here is the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".button").click(function(e) {

    $(this).slideUp(2000)
  });
});
```

I simply wanna hide the div which has the class "button" when I click on it.
Help appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: You do not include the jQuery library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select jQuery library from left side of site in section Frameworks & Extensions

Answer (score 0):

You did not include jQuery library in your code.

Check out the update; http://jsfiddle.net/HEM7Q/3/

```
Include jQuery library
```